# why flask app run host not working in newer version?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful, werkzeug

I am creating a rest api with flask restful using the below versions.

```
Werkzeug==2.0.1, 
Flask-RESTful==0.3.9, 
Flask==2.0.1
```

If I run my app with specifying host and port

```py
app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5001,debug=True)
```

I am getting http://192.168.1.9:5001/ instead if http://0.0.0.0:5001.
The port is changing but not host.
I changed the versions to

```
Werkzeug==1.0.1, 
Flask-RESTful==0.3.9, 
Flask==1.0.1
```

then its working in older version.Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: "I am getting" - in app logs, right? Or are you trying to actually access that 0.0.0.0:5001?

Comment: yes, I am getting in app logs.But i can't get remote access.

Comment: So it seems correct. You're not listening on your localhost (default value, 127.0.0.1) and your only public ip address for that machine is 192.168.1.9. How are you trying to access it? From where and with what address?

Comment: Through LAN network with my local ip 192.168.1.9:5001

Comment: And it's working with that older flask? Or is only the log info changing?

Comment: Its only working with older version of Werkzeug(1.0.1). I think its not a problem with flask.

Comment: @h4z3 I got the answer and thank you for the support

Answer (score 2):

Its not a problem with flask or Werkzeug 
I run the below command and now I can access remotely

```sh
sudo ufw allow 5001
```